# Pycharm debugger traceback errors

Tags: python, debugging

I get the following errors only when I ran Pycharm debugger.

1. I do not get it while running the code without the debugger.
2. The Code is managed by Git and debugs successfully on other co-workers environments.
3. Reinstalling Pycharm didn't help.

Any Idea?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXXX/bin/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydevd_comm.py", line 1071, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "/home/XXXX/bin/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydevd_vars.py", line 344, in evaluateExpression
    Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "/home/XXXX/bin/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<string>", line 1
    testInit.GetVar(<XXXX>)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


    Process ReportManager-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 558, in _run_server
    server.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 184, in serve_forever
    t.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 746, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
error: can't start new thread
Exception in thread Thread-287:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 811, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 764, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/XXXX/devel/gitlab//modules/XXXX/report.py", line 1305, in __SyslogThread
    printCmd=False if logLevel == 'ACTION' else True)
  File "/home/XXXX/devel/gitlab//modules/XXXX/host.py", line 375, in Run
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
  File "/home/XXXX/bin/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydev_monkey.py", line 318, in new_fork
    child_process = getattr(os, original_name)() # fork
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: Which version of pycharm are you using?